# How to map json to java object using json property

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I can not map this json in java object. issue is i can not map the values v0.1.0 to my java object can any one help me how i can map this json to java object.I am not declare varaible name with v0.1.0 so i use json property annotation . but this is not work for me.

How to make java object from this json :

```
{
    "availableVariants": {
        "v0.1.0": {
            "resourceName": "raja",
            "get": "www.google.com",
            "deltaGet": "",
            "post": null,
            "put": null,
            "delete": null
        },
        "v1.1.0": {
            "resourceName": "raja",
            "get": "www.google.com",
            "deltaGet": "",
            "post": null,
            "put": null,
            "delete": null
        }
    }
}

I am not able to make java object for this json .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the problem get simpler if you think of "v0.1.0" and "v1.1.0" as keys in a map instead of properties of an object? Try something like this:

```
public class Resource {
    private String resourceName;
    private String get;
    private String deltaGet;
    private String post;
    private String put;
    private String delete;

    // public getters and setters
}

public class VariantInfo {
    // resources indexed by version
    private Map<String, Resource> availableVariants; 
    // public getter and setter
}

public VariantInfo parseVariants(String json) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = (wherever your Jackson object mapper comes from);
    return objectMapper.readValue(json, VariantInfo.class);
}
```